# creating and updating an ObjectBox 1:n relationship

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I am a bit confused with the [documentation](https://docs.objectbox.io/relations#one-to-many-1-n). Let's stay with the customer order relationship, where a customer can have n orders.

If I create a new order for an existing customer and store this with

```dart
Customer customer = Customer();
customer.orders.add(Order()); // Order #3
customer.orders.add(Order()); // Order #4
// Puts customer and orders:
final customerId = store.box<Customer>().put(customer);
```

I expect this to update the customer (overwriting all data) because I am using the id of the customer. And I guess, the new orders #3 and #4 are created as new orders and linked to the customer, because their order id is 0. But what happens with my orders I have stored previously (#1 & #2)? Do they remain linked to my customer? Or is this link overwritten as well and as such lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, your code example would create a new customer. To update an existing customer and its relation, first get the existing customer from the store (or re-use the previously put customer instance).

```
Customer customer = store.box<Customer>().get(customerId);
customer.orders.add(Order()); // Order #3
customer.orders.add(Order()); // Order #4
store.box<Customer>().put(customer);
```

The [documentation](https://docs.objectbox.io/relations#one-to-many-1-n) also shows how to get and remove objects from a ToMany relation.

Comment: `Customer customer = Customer();` was a copy-paste error. Of course customer needs to come from the ObjectBox with the id. But the question whether updating this with only customer and order 3 & 4 will keep the relation to order 1 & 2 remains. Anyways, since relations in ObjectBox do not support my layered architecture so well (with transforming nested data types), I meanwhile store nested data as a json string and not as a relation

Comment: When you get the `Customer` from the database the ToMany contains existing related objects. If you remove them and only add order 3 and 4 the relation to order 1 and 2 will be dissolved when putting the `Customer`.